# What makes a series of machine instructions an actual process/thread in memory?

Tags: multithreading

Every instruction comes from main memory/RAM.

In a bootloader, at least on Intel and IBM PC firmware and designations, you
have BIOS jump to a memory address to begin fetching instructions for whatever
purpose, usually to load a kernel, when or where does the instance of a process begin?

The hardware stacks are limited, but does using them constitute for a process or thread?

My point simply is what makes something a "thread" or "process", as to opposed to
just more bytes from memory? Where is the line drawn in this situation?

Comment: The distinction appears as soon as two or more [contexts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) exist in the system, and the kernel provides a way to switch between the contexts.

Comment: Are you sure? I really don't think it works that simply.

Comment: I also think context switching is more suited to multitasking kernels rather than just simply one process, multiple threads or not. That is why I am asking if something specific entails this.

Comment: Thread/Process are OS concepts. But even then they are very generic terms. But "Processes" could be considered to be running programs that can be scheduled by the OS. A "Thread of execution" is (current register state/stack) also known as a context. A context is something that can be scheduled by the OS to run on a particular processes. A processes contains at least one thread.

Comment: I knew all of that. That doesn't addres my question exactly though.

Comment: Don't you think that Wikipedia is more appropriate place to get an answer on CS question like that - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)#Process_states ? "...While the process is "waiting" it waits for the scheduler to do a so-called context switch and load the process into the processor. The process state then becomes "running", and the processor executes the process instructions."

Comment: Look at the Linux kernel's scheduler. It determines what bytes from RAM are next to execute. Another instance is the interupt controller.

Comment: Some architectures (old transputers, modern GPUs) do have hardware-implemented threads, and this is where things gets complicated. But in general it's nothing but a hardware timer interrupt and a bit of an OS kernel code which does the context switching, no specific hardware support is required.

Comment: This is a very subjective sort of question, because it depends on your definition of "process". Arguably, a process is anything that uses the CPU, with some subjective decisions what the boundaries between processes are. In that view, the CPU is executing a process as soon as it starts up (though the "process image" is loaded from BIOS).

Answer (score 3):

The BIOS finds the kernel bootloader and jumps to that. The kernel loads process zero -- at this point the kernel has total control over the processor and RAM. When the kernel wants to start a new process, it saves the state of the current process, allocates space in memory for the new process, and loads the initial state of the new process. The stack is just some available space given to a process by the kernel. It works like the memory is allocated before the process starts and freed after the process ends. The stack is limited because for C it needs to be contiguous -- to extend the stack, the kernel has to use the MMU to map a space in memory. If you don't ask the kernel first, you go past the end of the stack into a region that the MMU marked as unreadable, causing an overflow.

There are a few ways to separate tasks.

Green threads are done by saving state and switching tasks without kernel support. The process would need to allocate new stack space or share stack space. Switching with green threads requires them to release control of the CPU and give it to another with a `yield` command or similar.

Kernel threads are given their own stack and task switching is done by the kernel's scheduler, and the kernel creates space for the thread's stack, but they belong to the same process so they can access the same memory.

Processes are segregated by the kernel, so they cannot access the memory of other processes under normal conditions. `fork`ing creates a new process with a copy (on write) of the memory used by the parent process.

I think these definitions are fairly typical, but a lot does depend on what the kernel and even language writers decided. For example, in Erlang, they use what I would refer to as "green threading" to create very light-weight threads, but describe these as "processes" (not unjustifiably, since they don't share memory).